# Cucumber doesn't work due to dyld (Library not loaded) issue

Tags: qt, ruby-on-rails-3.2, qt4, cucumber, capybara-webkit

when running cucumber on my osx I am facing an issue .I am using capybara version 2.1.0 and capybara-webkit version 1.0.0

Log.

```
   satyammacmini:New_Beast satyam$ cucumber features -f junit -o testresults -t  @SearchRoom_TileView_logged_out
/Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:220: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Webkit...
2014-02-20 15:17:08 +0530
dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit
  Referenced from: /Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/bin/webkit_server
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit
  Referenced from: /Users/satyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/bin/webkit_server
  Reason: image not found
```

I could not find any solution on the net for the same.
latest version of Xcode ie 5.0.2 and command line tools are also installed.
Qmake version:

```
satyammacmini:New_Beast satyam$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
**Using Qt version 4.8.5 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.5/lib**
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if your version of rvm might be using a local install of ruby vs. the OSX system install (which xcode uses).

Type

```
env
```

...into terminal and post your output. If you have to type

```
sudo gem install __
```

versus

```
gem install __
```

that's a good indicator also.

Comment: I reinstalled ruby and all the gems. And the same was working . N thanks for the info Michael .Highly appritiated